# Expressão regular em C# - Regex que aceite números com DDD e que aceite números sem DDD

Tags: c#

Gente, como eu faço para criar um expressão regular, na qual ela deva aceitar números com DDD, e também deva aceitar números sem DDD?

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\([0-9]{2}\)|)[0-9]{4,5}-[0-9]{4}");
reg.isMatch("(12)12345-1234"); //retorna true
reg.isMatch("(12)1234-1234"); //retorna true
reg.isMatch("12345-1234"); //retorna true
reg.isMatch("1234-1234"); //retorna true
reg.isMatch("123-1234"); //e qualquer outra combinação retorna false
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Leandro... 
O meu erro era que eu não estava colocando parênteses nessa parte :  @"(\([0-9]{2}\)|).
Agradeço pelo seu auxílio.

Comment: @FelipeMoreira, se a resposta resolveu seu problema, você pode marcar como **Resposta**.